# How do I make a variable that can store a queue or a stack?

Tags: java, interface

I have an object that has a variable that I want to be able to hold either a queue or a stack. Anything that has an add and a remove with the appropriate logics. I think this can be done with an interface but the two in `java.util` doesn't have the same interface or even the same name for the two operations.

My plan right now is to create a wrapper to make them fit what I want, but this seems inelegant. Is there a better way?

I want something like:

```
Something<E> steps;
```

So that I can call step.pop() and step.push() or whatever method names without having to know if steps implements queue logic or stack logic.

Comment: Why exactly don't `java.util.Queue<E>` and `java.util.Stack<E>` work for you?

Comment: It has to be a single variable of Something<> that can store either

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want either [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) or [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) depending on your needs.

Both implement [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (double ended queue).

From the Javadoc on `ArrayDeque`: "This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue."

Elements can be added or removed from either end of a `Deque`.

A `Deque` can be used as a queue by calling `addLast` and `removeFirst`, and can also be used by a stack by using `addLast` and `removeLast`.

If you really want it to behave like either one, you can keep a boolean flag and write helper methods, or you can write a class:

```
public class QueueOrStack<E> implements Iterable<E> {

    private Deque<E> container = new ArrayDeque<E>();
    private boolean isQueue;

    public QueueOrStack(boolean isQueue) {
        this.isQueue = isQueue;
    }

    public E pop() {
        return isQueue ? container.removeFirst() : container.removeLast();
    }

    public void push(E element) {
        container.addLast(element);
    }

    public void pushAll(E... element) {
        for (E e : element)
            container.addLast(e);
    }

    public boolean isQueue() {
        return isQueue;
    }

    public void setQueue(boolean isQueue) {
        this.isQueue = isQueue;
    }

    public boolean toggleQueue() {
        return isQueue = !isQueue;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        return container.iterator();
    }
}
```

Here's the test:

```
QueueOrStack<String> strings = new QueueOrStack<>(true);
strings.pushAll("hello", ", " , "world\n");
for(String s : strings)
    System.out.print(s); //"hello, world"
System.out.println(strings.pop()); //"hello"
strings.toggleQueue();
System.out.println(strings.pop()); //"world"
```

Comment: I want something like Something<E> steps where I can call steps.pop() and step.push() without having to think about if it is a queue or a stack. LinkedList seems to require you to make a choice

Comment: @TimothyElbert [`Queue`s don't have `pop` or `push` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) either way, but you could write helper methods or a separate class (which you mentioned in your question.) I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @TimothyElbert Edited.